# When will Go scheduler create a new M and P?

Tags: multithreading, go, operating-system, schedule, goroutine

Just learned golang GMP model, now I understand how goroutines, OS threads, and golang contexts/processors cooperate with each other. But I still don't understand when will an M and P be created?

For example, I have a test code to run some operations on DB and there are two test cases (two batches of goroutines):

```
func Test_GMP(t *testing.T) {
    for _ = range []struct {
        name string
    }{
        {"first batch"},
        {"second batch"},
    } {
        goroutineSize := 50
        done := make(chan error, goroutineSize)
        for i := 0; i < goroutineSize; i++ {
            go func() {
                // do some databases operations...
                // each goroutine should be blocked here for some time...

                // propogate the result
                done <- nil
            }()
        }

        for i := 0; i < goroutineSize; i++ {
            select {
            case err := <-done:
                assert.NoError(t, err)
            case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
                t.Fatal("timeout waiting for txFunc goroutine")
            }
        }
        close(done)
    }
}
```

In my understanding, if M is created in need. In the first batch of goroutines, 8 (the number of virtual cores on my computer) OS threads will be created and the second batch will just reuse the 8 OS threads without creating new ones. Is that correct?

Appreciate if you can provide more materials or blogs on this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M is reusable only if your processes are not blocking or not any sys-calls. In your case you have blocking tasks inside your `go func()`. So, number of M will not be limited to 8 (the number of virtual cores on my computer). First batch will block and remove from P and wait for blocking processes get finished while new M create an associate with P.

> 1. We create a goroutine through Go func ();
> 2. There are two queues that store G, one is the local queue of local scheduler P, one is the global G queue. The newly created G will be
>    saved in the local queue in the P, and if the local queues of P are
>    full, they will be saved in the global queue;
> 3. G can only run in m, one m must hold a P, M and P are 1: 1
>    relationship. M will pop up a executable G from the local queue of P.
>    If the local queue is empty, you will think that other MP combinations
>    steals an executable G to execute;
> 4. A process executed by M Scheduling G is a loop mechanism;
> 5. When M executes syscall or the remaining blocking operation, M will block, if there are some g in execution, Runtime will remove this
>    thread M from P, then create one The new operating system thread (if
>    there is an idle thread available to multiplex idle threads) to serve
>    this P;
> 6. When the M system call ends, this G will try to get an idle P execute and put it into this P's local queue. If you get P, then this
>    thread m becomes a sleep state, add it to the idle thread, and then
>    this G will be placed in the global queue.
>
> **1.  P Quantity:**
>
> The environment variable $ GomaxProcs is determined by the Runtime
> method gomaxprocs () when the environment variable is scheduled. After
> GO1.5, GomaxProcs will be set by default to the available cores, and
> before default it is 1.This means that only $ GOMAXPROCS Goroutine is
> run at the same time at any time executed.
>
> **2.   M quantity:**
>
> The GO language itself limits: When the GO program starts, the maximum
> number of M will set the maximum number of M. However, the kernel is
> difficult to support so many threads, so this limit can be ignored.
> SetMaxThreads function in runtime / debug, set the maximum number of M
> A M blocking, you will create new M.
>
> The number of M and P has no absolute relationship, one m block, p
> will create or switch another M, so even if the default number of P is
> 1, there may be many M out.

Please refer following for more details,

- https://www.programmersought.com/article/79557885527/
- [go-goroutine-os-thread-and-cpu-management](https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-goroutine-os-thread-and-cpu-management-2f5a5eaf518a)