# what does producer and consumer mean in mpmc?

Tags: go

In `GMP` concurrent model in Go programming language, what are producers and consumers?

Is it a queue or are the tasks in the queue producers?

Is it a thread or a coroutine, or is the processor a consumer?

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68312630/16182150). When the `go` keyword is used, a coroutine is created (producer). This coroutine will be stored in queue P. M takes out G from the queue and executes it, that is, the consumer.

Comment: See [this](https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler) and [this](https://rakyll.org/scheduler/).

Comment: @meshkati yes, the accepted answer in the post is really good.